# error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token when using template

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a custom dynamic array class using templates, and currently the `.h` file looks like this:

```cpp
//
// Created by juanfra on 10/10/22.
//

#ifndef IMAGENES_VDINAMICO_H
#define IMAGENES_VDINAMICO_H

#include <cmath>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class VDinamico {
private:
    int tamL, tamF;
    T *contenedor;
public:
    // CONSTRUCTORES
    VDinamico<T>();

    VDinamico<T>(int tamLog);

    VDinamico<T>(const VDinamico<T> &origen);

    VDinamico<T>(const VDinamico<T> &origen, unsigned int posicionInicial, unsigned int numElementos);

    // OPERADORES
    VDinamico &operator=(const VDinamico<T> &vector);

    T operator[](int i);

    // FUNCIONES
    void insertar(const T &dato, unsigned int pos = UINT_MAX);

    T borrar (unsigned int pos = UINT_MAX);

    bool isGreater(const T& i, const T& j);

    void ordenar();

    void ordenarRev();

    // GETTERS Y SETTERS
    int getTamL() const;

    void setTamL(int tamL);

    int getTamF() const;

    void setTamF(int tamF);

    T *getContenedor() const;

    void setContenedor(T *contenedor);
};

#endif //IMAGENES_VDINAMICO_H
```

While the `.cpp` file looks like this:

```cpp
//
// Created by juanfra on 10/10/22.
//

#include "VDinamico.h"

template<class T>
VDinamico<T>::VDinamico() {
    tamF = tamL = 0;
    contenedor = new T[tamF];
}

template<class T>
VDinamico<T>::VDinamico(int tamLog) {
    tamL = tamLog;
    tamF = pow(tamL, 2.0);
    contenedor = new T[tamF];
}

template<class T>
VDinamico<T>::VDinamico(const VDinamico<T> &origen) {
    tamL = origen.tamL;
    tamF = origen.tamF;
    contenedor = new T[tamF];
    for (int i = 0; i < tamL; i++) {
        contenedor[i] = origen.contenedor[i];
    }
}

template<class T>
VDinamico<T>::VDinamico(const VDinamico<T> &origen, unsigned int posicionInicial, unsigned int numElementos) {
    tamL = numElementos;
    tamF = pow(tamL, 2.0);
    contenedor = new T[tamF];
    for (int i = 0; i < numElementos; i++) {
        contenedor[i] = origen.contenedor[i + posicionInicial];
    }
}

// OPERADORES
template<class T>
VDinamico<T> &VDinamico<T>::operator=(const VDinamico<T> &vector) {
    tamL = vector.tamL;
    tamF = vector.tamF;
    contenedor = new T[tamF];
    T *contenedorAux = vector.contenedor;
    for (int i = 0; i < tamL; i++) {
        contenedor[i] = contenedorAux[i];
    }
}

template<class T>
T VDinamico<T>::operator[](int i) {
    return contenedor[i];
}

// FUNCIONES
template<class T>
void VDinamico<T>::insertar(const T &dato, unsigned int pos) {
    tamF = this->getTamF();
    tamL = this->getTamL();
    if (tamF == tamL) { //< Si los tamanyos son iguales, duplico tamF e inserto
        T *vAux = new T[tamF * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < tamL; i++) {
            vAux[i] = contenedor[i];
        }
        delete[]contenedor;
        contenedor = vAux;
    }
    if (pos == UINT_MAX) { //< Si la posición no se indica, insertamos por el final
        contenedor[tamL++] = dato;
    } else { //< Si la posición se indica, abrimos un hueco en la posición indicada copiando el resto del vector
        for (int i = tamL - 1; i >= pos; i--) {
            contenedor[i + 1] = contenedor[i];
        }
    }
    this->setTamL(tamL + 1);
}

template<class T>
T VDinamico<T>::borrar(unsigned int pos) {
    tamF = this->getTamF();
    tamL = this->getTamL();
    if (tamL*3 < tamF){ //< Si tamL es 3 veces menor que tamF, hago un nuevo vector de tamF/2
        T *vAux = new T[tamF/2];
        for (int i = 0; i < tamL; i++){
            vAux[i] = contenedor[i];
        }
        delete[]contenedor;
        contenedor = vAux;
    }
    if (pos == UINT_MAX){
        return contenedor[tamL--];
    } else {
        for (int i = pos; i < tamL; i++){
            contenedor[i] = contenedor[i+1];
        }
    }
    this->setTamL(tamL--);
    return contenedor;
}

template<class T>
bool VDinamico<T>::isGreater(const T& i, const T& j) {
    return (i.getId() > j.getId());
}

template<class T>
void VDinamico<T>::ordenar() {
    sort(contenedor, contenedor + tamL);
}

template<class T>
void VDinamico<T>::ordenarRev() {
    sort(contenedor, contenedor + tamL, isGreater());
}

// GETTERS Y SETTERS
template<class T>
int VDinamico<T>::getTamL() const {
    return tamL;
}

template<class T>
void VDinamico<T>::setTamL(int tamL) {
    VDinamico::tamL = tamL;
}

template<class T>
int VDinamico<T>::getTamF() const {
    return tamF;
}

template<class T>
void VDinamico<T>::setTamF(int tamF) {
    VDinamico::tamF = tamF;
}

template<class T>
T *VDinamico<T>::getContenedor() const {
    return contenedor;
}

template<class T>
void VDinamico<T>::setContenedor(T *contenedor) {
    VDinamico::contenedor = contenedor;
}
```

My problem is that, in the `.h`, everytime I use `<T>`, it throws me an error like:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token in line 20
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’ in line 22
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’ in line 24
and so on...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove all of the `<T>`'s in the `.h` file, you don't need them. Everywhere the `.h` file says `VDinamico<T>`, it should be just `VDinamico` instead.  Using `VDinamico<T>` in the `.cpp` file is correct, except that [you can't split a template class across `.h`/`.cpp` files the way you are doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/) to begin with

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot! Thanks, everything working fine now @sweenish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all the `<T>` in the `.h` file, to not split a template class across `.h` and `.cpp` files.

Here is why: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/)